# differences beetween Surpass & Exceed

Tags: differences

I'm confused beetween two words when i tried to conplete this sentence :
 Sales of the TX 20 digital camera recently .... 10.000 in total
  A.Surpassed
  B.Exceeded
The key gives A , but i don't know why
please help me , thanks

Comment: *Surpass* has a positive connotation, kind of an achievement most of the time, while *exceed* is essentially neutral and can take positive or negative connotations depending on context.

Comment: It's a silly test, and anyone who claims ***surpassed*** is somehow the "correct" answer is an idiot. In fact there's probably a stronger case for saying the answer should be ***exceeded*** if it has to be one of those two, but if you're just learning English you should forget both of them and go with the simpler ***passed***.

Comment: In the given context, *surpassed* is obviously incorrect, *exceeded* it should be. The key must be a typo, I am sure. Do not use *surpass* with respect to absolute values, only to compare with another parameter: *Sales of the TX 20 digital camera **surpassed those of ZZ30***.

Comment: @Kris: I don't know about you, but idiomatically I don't think ***surpass*** works at all well in relation to *scalar values*. It's normally only used of *people*, or "things" which deliver "performances" that can be compared to others in order to decide which is "best".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I always enjoy your subtle and nuanced opinions on grammarians and textbook writers who, in your opinion, tend to postulate less-than-accurate views in guise of holy writ in teaching :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Will the euro eventually surpass the dollar as leading ...*; *Making the Gladiolus Surpass Itself ...* https://www.google.com/#q=surpass&tbm=bks

Comment: From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exceed): ***exceed** implies going beyond a limit set by authority or established by custom or by prior achievement <exceed the speed limit>. **surpass** suggests superiority in quality, merit, or skill <the book surpassed our expectations>*. In many contexts they're interchangeable, but in OP's example, ***surpassed*** definitely *doesn't* work. *"X surpasses Y"* is never correct when Y is a scalar (countable) value, and *"X exceeds Y"* is never correct when Y is a "defeated competitor".

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 3):

From: http://dictionary.cambridge.org

Surpass : To do or be better than
: His time for the 100 meters surpassed the previous world record by one hundredth of a second. The book's success has surpassed everyone's expectations. The director has really surpassed himself (= done better than he has done before) with this new film

Exceed : To be greater than a number or amount, or to go beyond a permitted limit:
 He was exceeding the speed limit by 15 miles an hour.

this is What I understand;  when you say surpass, you compare one thing that has gone beyond another thing which has previously known as a record or  expectation from its ability , and exceed means going beyond a  permitted limit or quantity   .

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "surpassed the 10,000 mark"

Comment: Why? We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).
At present this expresses your opinion; we are looking for responses that definitively answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Exceed is always a **surpassed or +** set amount or number and surpass is both negative, good or bad, **+ or -** Companies often PR release that they have exceeded a competitor's sales, not that they have surpassed a competitor's sales.

**Surpassed** is a target that is both + or - **[number and quantity](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/172488/Surpass)**

**Exceeded** is a + **[number and quantity](http://business_finance.enacademic.com/19295/exceed)**

Comment: Please give an example where *surpass* can be used negatively and *exceed* cannot. It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to say. Google finds 10 hits for *exceeded in smallness* and 20 for *surpassed in smallness*, which doesn't strike me as that significant.

Comment: @Peter: "Difficult" might be a bit of an understatement there! I'm completely at a loss - probably mainly because I can't actually *articulate* the difference myself. Initially I thought Kris's *Euro surpassing the dollar* was a telling example of usage differences, but on reflection I think that's a slightly "aberrant" usage where the word of choice should really be ***overtake***.